# Windows 11 cannot recognize my Xiaomi note 11 pro phone

Tags: drivers, android, windows-11, xiaomi

I've installed windows 11 22h2 recently but it cannot recognize my Xiaomi note 11 pro like windows 10 was doing, I also tried to download and install mediatek driver and Xiaomi ABD driver but nothing seems to work. is there any solution to this problem?
I want to transfer files from my pc to my phone using USB cable.

Comment: If Windows 11 does not recognize the phone, it is likely not compatible. The most obvious solution then is to (a) set up a Windows 10 virtual machine or (b) find a good friend with a Windows 10 physical machine.

Comment: Windows 10 and 11 are next to identical when it comes to USB. Most likely a wrong driver has been assigned and is now blocking access. Is only ADB active or also MTP? What devices appear in Windows device manager when you connect your phone?

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, when you say the computer does not recognize your phone? Do you mean you cannot file or media transfer, or Hotspot, or charge, or access debugging mode, or something else? You say that you want to file transfer, but do any of these other modes work?